# Preventing :make in VIM from going to a warning

Tags: vim, makefile, warnings

I have a warning I can not easily remove from my build, every time i run ":make" from inside vim the quickfix takes me to some header file I don't care about. How can I prevent VIM from doing this and only showing me warnings and errors I do care about?

Answer (score 13):

As Luc Hermite said, it is possible to ignore warnings using `'errorformat'`option.
Adjusting this option is a little bit complicated; it may be helpful to check `$VIMRUNTIME/compiler` for some examples.

When working with avr-gcc and C++ some annoying warnings like this

```
tests.cpp:492: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
```

shows up, and it is likely to be result of a [compiler fault](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=62004&start=0).

To avoid that this warnings being displayed on quickfix window I've add this to `~/.vimrc`:

```
compiler gcc
set errorformat^=%-G%f:%l:\ %tarning:\ only\ initialized\ varia
            \bles\ can\ be\ placed\ into\ program\ memory\ area
```

The `%-G` can be used to specify patterns to be ignored. 
The `^=` in `set errorformat^=...` is used to prepend the ignored warning pattern to `'errorformat'` -- using `+=` (`set errorformat+=...`) would append to the option and wouldn't work, as `'errorformat'` is a list of formats and the first one that matches is used, thus the "normal" warning pattern would apply instead.

Maybe you could adapt these settings for your environment.

Comment: Only memorize `%.%#` which is just regexp `.*`, and you can `set errorformat ^=%-G%.%#warning_message%.%#` which will remove any lines having substring `warning_message`. Remember to prepend, not append, to errorformat. This won't let the pattern match the file name like you wanted, but if the warning is specific enough this will do. Only learn the more complicated stuff if needed.

Comment: Tried this with neovim and it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @AcidTonic, this is not surprising, since the answer was given four years before neovim was even created. Anyway, the reference to the documentation should still be relevant (`errorformat`), so you can look up the changes in the current version and adapt if it necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Check `:h 'errorformat'` (aka `&efm`), there are options to ignore warnings as long as you can recognize them with a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way would be to write a simple shell script that runs your make and greps out the warnings you don't want to see.  Then have vim use this script instead of make (Add "set makeprg=yourscript.sh" to your .vimrc).

Answer (score 3):

To build on what mMontu suggested, adding this to my .vimrc did the trick for me (ignore all warnings from my gcc compiler)

set errorformat^=%-G%f:%l:\ warning:%m

Answer (score 1):

Learn from Bram himself.

I can vaguely remember he talks about this somewhere in [this video](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2538831956647446078).

He adds a filter to ignore some  gnome warnings when he's compiling gvim.

The video's well worth watching anyway.

It's around the 30 minute mark.

Comment: The link is dead, any idea what the talk was called?